# Differential equation solved by $y(x) = c_1e^x + c_2xe^x + c_3x^2e^x + c_4\cos(x) + c_5\sin(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider the following solution: $$y(x) = c_1e^x + c_2xe^x + c_3x^2e^x + c_4\cos(x) + c_5\sin(x)$$
>   where all the $c_i$ are real constants ($c_i \in \Bbb R$).
>   How to find a differential equation that have the previous solution?

I re-wrote the solution to the following:

$$y(x)=(c_1 + c_2x + c_3x^2)e^x + c_4\cos(x) + c_5\sin(x)$$

I can see that the solution looks like: $y(x) = Q(x)e^x + a\cos(x) + b\sin(x)$ where $Q$ is a second degree polynomial, but I don't really know how to take it from here.

Comment: You need to look at the annihilation method: http://dankalman.net/AUhome/classes/classesF12/odes/assignments/annihilatormethod.pdf

Comment: If you have a solution, why not just take a differential and see what you'll get?

Comment: @Vasya can the final equation still have C's ? because even if I derive it more than two time I will always have constants for $y'', y'$...etc

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales That was a nice one. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
\text{Operator} &\quad& \text{ Annihilates}\\
D^{n+1} && Q_n(x)\text{ a degree n polynomial}\\
D-a && e^{ax}\\
(D-a)^{n+1} && Q_n(x)e^{ax}\\
D^2+b^2 && c_1\cos(bx)+c_2\sin(bx)\\
(D^2+b^2)^{n+1} && Q_n(x)(c_1\cos(bx)+ c_2\sin(bx))\\
D^2-2aD+(a^2+b^2) && e^{ax}(c_1\cos(bx)+ c_2\sin(bx))\\
\left(D^2-2aD+(a^2+b^2)\right)^{n+1} &&Q_n(x)e^{ax}(c_1\cos(bx)+ c_2\sin(bx))
\end{eqnarray}
If operator $L_1$ annihilates $f(x)$ and operator $L_2$ annihilates $g(x)$ then operator $L_1L_2$ annihilates $f(x)+g(x)$.

$(D-1)^3$ annihilates $(c_1+c_2x+c_3x^2)e^x$

$(D^2+1)$ annihilates $c_4\cos(x)+c_5\sin(x)$

so  $(D-1)^3(D^2+1)$ annihilates their sum.

So $$y = c_1e^x + c_2xe^x + c_3x^2e^x + c_4\cos(x) + c_5\sin(x)$$ is the general solution of

$$ (D-1)^3(D^2+1)y=0 $$

which is

$$ y^{(5)}-3y^{(4)}+4y^{(3)}-4y^{\prime\prime}+3y^\prime-y=0 $$

Answer (score 0):

$c_4\cos (x)+c_5\sin (x) $ could be seen as the solution of $$y''+y=0$$

and $(c_1+c_2x+c_3x^2)e^x $ is a particular solution of

$$y''+y=(a_1+a_2x+a_3x^2)e^x $$

Comment: No, $(c_1+c_2x+c_3x^2)e^x $ is not a particular solution, because of the constants $(c_1,c_2,c_3)$.

Answer (score 0):

You need $5$ derivatives because of those $5$ constants. It's routine that
$$(D-1)^3(D^2+1)y=y^{(5)}-3y^{(4)}+4y^{(3)}-4y^{\prime\prime}+3y^{\prime}-y=0$$

Comment: My guess is that the OP is asking about the step you call "routine" and that you omit. Thus, this is no help. (BTW, I fully agree this is "routine", but.)

Comment: @Did I admit it's not a great answer, but if you take the time to typeset a really useful answer often the question has been vandalized by a small group of posters whose answers, though superficial, take precedence because they were posted first. But that's a topic for Meta. Sometimes I post what I think is a really impressive answer and don't get any love and sometimes an answer as uninspired as the above goes viral. The accepted answer ended up reposting a page of the kid's textbook, which I guess is OK because textbooks are so expensive today that many students can't buy them.